# Reopen opinion-based question to close as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

I'd like to [reopen this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833981/what-should-my-swap-size-be-if-i-have-32gb-of-ram/833990) to close it again afterwards as a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-1tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) and would like to get some input from the community before I start the reopen process as ***I might be biased because I answered that question***...  **0:-)**

**Why?**

Well, because it seems to [be referenced as canon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071007/separate-file-for-hibernation-why-use-swap) and in my humble opinion the other question is not opinion-based but based on tangible data.

Comment: I like [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/594402/250300) but isn’t the question you answered actually duplicate of [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap) Gotta link ’em all!

Comment: In my opinion no, because all these are single point in time questions and answers whereas [How much swap should i take for 1GB to 1TB of RAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-1tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) encompasses them all. @Melebius so the others should be closed as dupes of the more generic one.  But like I said: I might be biased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was reopened and afterwards it was closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-1tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) as was requested. Putting my own two cents in I also don't agree that [How much swap should I take for 1GB to 1TB of RAM on 14.04 or higher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594054/how-much-swap-should-i-take-for-1gb-to-1tb-of-ram-on-14-04-or-higher) is an exact duplicate of [I have 16GB RAM. Do I need 32GB swap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap) as was discussed in the comments that were posted below this Meta question. In the end "How much swap should I take for 1GB to 1TB of RAM on 14.04 or higher?" was left open.

Comment: Secretly, I agree, openly, I do not!  **:D**